# algorithm interview: mth frequent element in n sorted arrays

Tags: algorithm

There is an algorithm interview question:

> We have n sorted arrays, how to find the m-th frequent element in the aggregated array of n arrays? Moreover, how to save space? Even compromise on some time complexity.

What I can think is that enumerate all the elements of n arrays and use a hashmap to record their frequency, then sort hashmap respect to the value (frequency). But then there is no difference with the one array case.

Comment: what is your attempted code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Walk over all arrays in parallel using `n` pointers

```
1 4 7 12 34
2 6 9 12 25
```

The walk would look like this

```
1  1  4  7  7  12 12 34
*  2  2  2  9  12 25 34
```

You do need a hash map in order to count the number of occurrences of elements in the cut. E.g. at the second step in the example, your cut contains 1 and 2.

Also, you need two min-heaps, one for every cut to be able to choose the array to advance along and another one to store `m` most repetitive elements.

The complexity would be *expected* `O(#elements * (log(n) + log(m)))`. The space requirement is `O(n + m)`.

---

But if you really need to save space you can consider all these `n` sorted arrays as one big unsorted, sort it with something like heapsort and choose the longest subarray of duplicates. This would require `O(#elements * log(#elements))` time but only `O(1)` space.

Answer (score 1):

You do an n-way merge, but instead of writing out the merged array, you just count the length of each run of duplicate values and remember the longest m in a min-heap.

This takes O(total_length * (log n + log m)) time, and O(n) space.

It's a combination of common SO questions.  Search above on "merge k sorted lists" and "kth largest"